# CiviCRM with Worpdress defaults to incorrect host?

Tags: configuration

I installed CiviCRM on my desktop installation of WordPress and everything worked fine. So I installed it on my working website, and after quite a bit of wrangling with the sysops, I got it to install. My problem is, when I go to configure it, it defaults to a different host than mine (eg., my host is nmsta.org and it goes to sfclt.org). I suspect the problem is in the database because it persists when I uninstall and reinstall it, even with two different versions. Any ideas where to start?

Comment: Actually, I tried ONE MORE TIME, this time I checked the box that said to install sample data and it works. Go figure....

Answer (score 1):

A clean installation of CiviCRM wouldn't come with any built-in hosts, so this sounds like a configuration issue, either in the CiviCRM settings or the WordPress settings. Perhaps if you search your codebase and database for the incorrect domain it would highlight the incorrect setting?